# C++, Visual Studio 2019: Me aparecen mas de 620 errores ¿Que hagi?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, sfml

Quiero aprender SFML para hacer videojuegos en C++, soy totalmente novato en C++ y Visual Studio 2019.

Luego de seguir tutoriales, instale exitosamente la libreria, hice el `int main()` pero me salen 621 errores en la consola

Este es el codigo:

```
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace sf;

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {

    return 0;
}
```

Y estos son los errores:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No tengo ni la menor idea porque aparecen tantos errores si el codigo esta bien ¿Que hago?

Saludos.

Comment: Sin tener ni idea de SFML, cuando salen tantos errores juntos, y además parecidos,  es porque falta incluir otros ficheros, definir valores, o añadir alguna librería.

Comment: hace muchisimo no uso c++ pero rapidamente veo que tenes mal incluida la primera libreria. Quitale las comillas

Comment: @Ramiro Barone las comillas dobles se usan para indicar un archivo relativo al que estás editando. Las angulares funcionan con todo lo que se encuentre en un directorio de inclusión definido en los ajustes del proyecto. Es por eso que por ejemplo, `iostream` no se encuentra en tu proyecto, sin embargo sabe dónde encontrarlo.

Comment: Agrega capturas de la configuración del proyecto, en concreto la parte de `VC++ Directories`, `C/C++ > General`, `Linker > General` y `Linker > Input`. Para corroborar que lo has configurado correctamente.